# How can I mount 2 drives on 1 directory

Tags: centos

The first drive has Raid 1 and has a partition mounted on /home the 2nd has 1 partition will all it's data and raid 0 how can I mount that on /home too?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a way to union filesystems on a moint point. This is what the [UnionFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) project set out to do, but it requires patching your kernel. A better solution is [unionfs-fuse](http://podgorny.cz/moin/UnionFsFuse), which uses fuse to do a union. This wouldn't require any kernel patching. I believe there is a CentOS package package for unionfs-fuse. The way you would use it would be to mount each partition to a directory that isn't /home, and then do the unionfs-fuse mount onto /home.